# Setting a data type as Date & Time only in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and I have a time and date column in each, is there a way to configure each result to only give me a date data type only when it returns, I have to switch it in myphp manually to date only and switch time to time only. I have checked the php manual but I cannot seem to find an answer on line.

```
    Print "<td><center>".$row['Transdate']."</center></td> ";
    Print "<td><center>".$row['Transtime']."</center></td> ";
```

Those are the two lines that I want to format, could you please give me an example to how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show mini example what you have and what you want to get. Right now it's unclear what you really want

Comment: Are you asking if it can return a php DateTime object?  Dates in MySQL return as strings to PHP.  You have to parse them yourself, or specify in your query string how you want them returned using MySQL's date functions.

Comment: Provide an example of your table structure. Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: "*I have to switch it in myphp manually to date only and switch time to time only*" - Do you mean "*I have to declare the column in PHPMyAdmin as `DATE` and `TIME` manually, but I want to keep it as `VARCHAR`*"? If so, that's wrong. You *should* save it as `DATE` and `TIME`. Also note that you should not print anything but tabular data in tables, and `center` (which isn't the same as `</centre>`) tags have been outdated pretty much since the early 2000's.

Comment: `I have a php database ` No such thing as a `php database`

Comment: @Justinas Here is the link to my page, http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=4313 the bottom of the page with the transactions section where it says date and time comes out with both date and time in each column, and I want it only to show date in one column and time in the other column. I use Microsoft Access to run my database and it only allows me to save the data types as datetime.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am trying to get around having to switch the column type as Date and Time manually, and was hoping to find a shortcut to set it in php. I am using MS Access which only allows me to save them as date/time I will fix the print and </center> tags as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it changed to other column type? Why do you have to change the type manually? Or are you referring to the values in your row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `datetime` column in your database. For example with ID 154 there is column named `Date` and it's value is `2014-05-20 09:15`. So you get that in variable `$row['Date']`:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['Date']);
$Transdate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp );
$Transtime = date('H:i', $timestamp );

echo $Transdate."<br/>".$Transtime
```

will print:

2014-05-20

09:15

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$originalDatetime = "2038-01-19 03:14:07";

list($datePortion, $timePortion) = explode(" ", $originalDatetime);
```

Or in the MySQL query itself:

```
SELECT DATE(myDatetimeColumn) as MyDate, TIME(myDatetimeColumn) as MyTime FROM myTable;
```